# Add a row before rendering tableview swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I am trying to add a row into my tableview before the `tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` method is called. I tried to do it into the `viewDidLoad()` method without success is it possible ? and how ?

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit

class CustomTestViewController : UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var formDetailTableView: UITableView!
    var data: Data?
    var firstData: FirstData?

    struct CurrentFormTableView {
        struct CellIdentifiers {
            static let MyCell = "MyCell"
            static let MyFirstCell = "MyFirstCell"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //HERE ADD THE FIRST ROW ?
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentFormTableView.CellIdentifiers.MyFirstCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyFirstCell
                    cell.displayCell(firstData)
                    return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentFormTableView.CellIdentifiers.MyCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell
                    cell.displayCell(data[indexPath.row])
                    return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: `tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`. For your information this method will not be triggered until you set the datasource  of your tableview to the viewcontroller.

Comment: **Do not** add a cell. Add an item to `data` and reload the table view.

Comment: thanks, but my firstData and my data is not the same architecture I can't add one to the other 
Thanks, @Roani for this information

Comment: What you can do is use an if-else statement inside `numberOfRowsInSection`, and call `self.tableView.reloadData` once you are sure the new row is ready to be added.

Comment: the first row will not be override by the other ? @MikeG

Comment: @vadian means by adding an item to `data` : I suppose that your `data` var is an array, in your `numberOfRowsInSection` method you define `return data.count`. `Data.count` returns the number of cells which will be created into your tableview. For now your `data` object is empty so it returns 0. So 0 cells are added to your tableview. Add an object into `viewDidLoad()` method to your `data` array. It will return 1 in `numberOfRowsInSection` method, so it will add 1 cell to your tableview. Do you understand?

Comment: Yes I understand, my only problem with this idea, is that my data array and my first element are not the same object so I can't add my first element to the data array easily

Comment: Your data array is of type of `Data?`. This type is a subclass of NSArray or something ?

Comment: Why don't you define your data array like that : 

`var data: [FirstData?]
 var firstData: FirstData?`

If you want that your data array contains FirstData objects ?

Comment: no data and first data are just here for explanation in reality I have a big object with a title and a description and in this object I have an array with content to display into my tableview controller. And I want to display the title and description at the first row of the tableview. Hope it's a bit clear

Comment: @ Anthony Roani Thanks a lot for the time you spend for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question properly this problem can be easily :)

You always wants to show a first cell in your tableView no matter whether there is a data in your data array or not :) and your problem is you cant add the first object to data array thats all right buddy :)

Here is a solution :)

Don't do anything in ViewDidLoad :) Simply save your first row data object in your local variable lets say : yourCustomObject

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count + 1
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : myTestCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("testCell")! as! myTestCell

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
             cell.nameLabel.text = yourCustomObject.property
        }
        else {
            cell.nameLabel.text = data[indexPath.row -1].property
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Problem solved :) Happy coding :)

**How It works :**
Simple,

Assume your data array is empty :) then it will return count as 0 :) But you always want to show your first cell isn't it :) so add +1 to data array count :) `return data.count + 1`

Now handle it carefully in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You dont want to end up accessing data in data array for first object so check for indexpath 0.

And you dont want to end up accessing object out of index of data so use `data[indexPath.row -1]`

Hope I made my point clear :) Happy coding

Comment: OH ! Nice idea ! I try it and tell you

Comment: @fandro : Please see my updated answer :) there was mistake in cell for row at indexpath code :) You cant say data[indexPath.row] you will end up array out of bound exception :) please try data[indexPath.row -1]

Comment: OK thanks, I'm debugging my project because I made a mistake and I will tell you I don't forget :)

Comment: @fandro : Glad I could help you buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count + 1 //Add plus 1 for firstData
 }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentFormTableView.CellIdentifiers.MyCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell

   if indexPath.row == 0 {//First index will be firstData
        cell.displayCell(firstData)    
   } else { //All other cell's will be filled with data array
        cell.displayCell(data[indexPath.row - 1]) //Make sure you offset indexPath.row by 1 so you start at index 0 of data array
   }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)